how to execute binary file from the C# .NET MAUI project and get the output
Tried to execute libimobiledevice idevice_id binary file from the C# MAUI Project but everytime i get,
Error: Unable to retrieve device list!
            var command = $"{Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Contents/Resources/bin/idevice_id")}";

            Process process = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo2 = process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "bash",
                Arguments = $"-c \"{command}\"",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = "/bin/"
            };
            Process process2 = process;
            process2.Start();
            while (!process2.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string text = ((TextReader)process2.StandardOutput).ReadToEnd();
                if (!text.Contains("Unable"))
                {
                    result = text;
                }
            }

            process2.WaitForExit();
            process.WaitForExit();

I tried to access the binary file from Console Application and it worked fine there.
What I want to achieve is to pack the binary file with the MAUI app and get the device UDID list.
I tried to access the binary file from Console Application and it worked fine there.
UPDATE: I have able to solve that problem. The issue was related to App Sandbox which was enabled in Entitlements.plist file. I had to remove that.

Is the working directory relevant? How do you execute the command on command line? Why execute bash and not execute the program directly? Does the program need privileges (like sudo)? Are you running it as the correct user?

Is the working directory relevant? [The working directory is set to a custom path to idevice_id binary file. Ex. Users/user/project/CSharpApp/build/bin. In that case when executing I get the operation not permitted error.]
How do you execute the command on command line?
Users/user/project/CSharpApp/build/bin/idevice_id - it work on zsh
why bash and not execute the program directly?
[did not found any library to work on libimobiledevice on Apple silicon]
program need privileges (like sudo)?
[No]
running it as the correct user?
[set privileges for the binary file]

Working directory: no, it isn't. Your code does not set the Working directory

How do you execute: that command uses a relative file. In that case, it matters in which directory you are in. Please add the console output to the question. Such details are needed for debugging.

Privileges: there are 2 parts to it: part a) set the privilege on the file and b) start the process as that user.

So, I have added the working directory to "/bin/" to access the bash. Also, put the binary files to the app package contents "Contents/Resource" folder. Now, when I debug or the standalone app, it does not work. The error is,
ERROR: Unable to retrieve the device list!
This is the only error I get.
The privileges are set to read, write and execution for everyone.  But, I actually don't know how to run as current user.

Github Repo
Here is the github code for the reference.

Not the working directory for bash, the working directory for command. Bash was obviously able to execute, otherwise it would not have been possible to execute anything. You are using Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), but is that where your executable lives?

Yes. I want to bundle the binary files into the App Package Contents so that I can access it from the app. Even though I have changed the working directory now for the command, I get ERROR: Unable to retrieve device list!
